# YouTube upload from iPhone going to wrong YouTube account

Tags: video, iphone, youtube, google

I have linked YouTube accounts. One is my personal Google+ account: [here](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCclbwJvNtDEd3AIeV5HpS-w?feature=watch) and the other is my normal YouTube page that I use for business videos, etc. [here.](http://youtube.com/bengreenfieldfitness)

Since I "merged" those accounts, it seems that every video I upload from my iPhone goes to the personal account, not the business account.

Anybody have any fixes for this, to force the iPhone to upload to a specific YouTube account?

Comment: Are you using the YouTube app by Google from the app store?

Answer (score 1):

YouTube lists the different ways to upload from mobile in [this support page](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57407?hl=en). For small uploads, I would suggest uploading by email. G mail limits you to [25 MB](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6584?hl=en). Please verify that your channels have unique email addresses, distinct of each other.

Another option is to use the [YouTube Capture app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/youtube-capture/id576941441?mt=8) which is available on the iTunes store. I do not have an iOS device so I cannot test this method.

Comment: The Youtube Capture App is a good piece of software and has good multi account integration.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this. Required signing out of Google+ app on iPhone then RE-signing in using correct Google+ account. Somehow YouTube camera capture on iPhone is tied to Google+ app on iPhone.

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  [You can mark your own answer as answered for the benefit of others.](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score -1):

try to sign out and log in again that should help. if that doesn't then try emailing youtube to help solve this issue